TypeError: The view function for 'user' did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement
I started flask a few days back and i'm facing this issue where i can't pass the user name. i've used jinja templating with flask.
this is the python file
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return "<h1>Hello!!</h1>"

@app.route("/user/<name>/")
def user(name):
    render_template("home.html", user_name = name)

this is the home.html
<h1>Hello {{ user_name }}</h1>


This question is similar to: Flask view return error "View function did not return a response". If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
